# How to get Powershell execution policy externally

Tags: powershell, executionpolicy

I need to find out the powershell (versions 4 and 5+) execution policy without using powershell itself

I tried to look into registry - HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PowerShell

I found ExecutionPolicy value in two keys, HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PowerShell\1\ShellIds\Microsoft.PowerShell and HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PowerShell\1\ShellIds\ScriptedDiagnostics

The first one corresponded to the policy given by executing Get-ExecutionPolicy cmdlet, but on some servers in our environment the value is missing. Is there any other, 100% reliable, way to check the policy without using Powershell itself?

Comment: On the servers where the value appears to be "missing," are the OS' different, or are running a different architecture (x64 vs x86), possibly?  For those that are missing, see if you find a hive/key pair here: `HKLM\software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\PowerShell\1\ShellIds\Microsoft.PowerShell\ExecutionPolicy`

Comment: It might not be in the registry.  Then it would use a default one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No key would equal **Undefined**

If the execution policy in all scopes is **Undefined**, the effective execution policy is **Restricted**, which is the default execution policy.

**x64**

**Current User**

```
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\PowerShell\1\ShellIds\Microsoft.PowerShell : ExecutionPolicy
```

**Local Machine**

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PowerShell\1\ShellIds\Microsoft.PowerShell : ExecutionPolicy
```

**x86**

**Local Machine**

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\PowerShell\1\ShellIds\Microsoft.PowerShell : ExecutionPolicy
```

**Machine Policy**

```
HKLM\Software\WOW6432Node\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\PowerShell : ExecutionPolicy
```

**User Policy**

```
HKCU\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\PowerShell : ExecutionPolicy
```